# Do I need a specific type of contractor to fix a water damaged floor beam?

Tags: beam, water-damage

I have a water damaged floor beam under my kitchen/over the crawl space and foundation of my house. I have contacted several contractors about repair but everyone says it's not their specialty. Is there a specialty I should be looking for? I am located east of Seattle for reference.

Comment: Most general building contractors should be able to do the work.  A picture of the water damage will help.  If it is rot then you do need someone in, but water stains you do not.

Comment: What do you mean by "water damage". I've never seen a beam that could be damaged by just water. Beams in structures under construction are routinely exposed to water for months on end, with no resulting damage.

Comment: Keep talking to licensed general contractors/ licensed handymen. You’ll eventually find someone, but expect to be surprised at what something seemingly simple will cost. (It’s a dirty crappy task, and GCs who are busy would say no in a heartbeat.)

Comment: are there any pass-throughs in the beam (like for power, water, etc)? If not, you can relatively easily sister it with a new beam and some extra temp framing/jacks. If it does demand utilities to be re-routed, that's a pain and probably why you get turned down; wood people are not electricity people...